# Writing to a file won't work

Tags: python

Even with the most basic of code, my .txt file is coming out empty, and I can't understand why. I'm running this subroutine in `python 3` to gather information from the user. When I open the .txt file in both notepad and N++, I get an empty file.

Here's my code :

```
def Setup():
    fw = open('AutoLoader.txt', 'a')

    x = True

    while x == True:
        print("Enter new location to enter")
        new_entry = str(input('Start with \'web\' if it\'s a web page\n'))
        fw.write(new_entry)

        y = input('New Data? Y/N\n')

        if y == 'N' or y == 'n':
            fw.close
            break

    fw.close
    Start()
```

Comment: Not your issue, but `fw.close` does not close your file! `fw.close()` does.

Comment: What does `Start()` do?

Comment: The issue _could_ be the `close`, depending on how this is being run. Because the file is not being properly closed, the data could be in a buffer when Ash opens the file in an editor.

Comment: Tried it on my machine, AutoLoader.txt is written correctly, without changing a single line of code. Other than fixing the call to close.

Comment: Just another remark, you can use double quotes for strings so you don't need escape characters for single quotes. `"Start with 'web' if it's a web page"`. Just looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: @1Up this could well be, because the garbage-collector properly destroys the `fw` when exiting the interpreter. something that might not happen when the code in question is still running...

Comment: @paulo-almeida Especially true if the Python script is still running (in the `Start` function) when you open it in the editor. `fw` should then be properly cleaned up and closed when it goes out of scope, i.e. when `Setup` finishes.

Comment: @Farhan.K The Start() is another function that is basically where the program starts. it basically restarts the program.

Comment: @zephyr I  hadnt even thought of that. Thank you

Comment: Also, you could just say "while x:" since x is boolean. And i think "if y in ('N', 'n'):" looks nicer though this is a personal opinion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing fw.close with fw.close()

Answer (score 1):

It's working on python 3.4

```
 def Setup():
 fw = open('AutoLoader3.4.txt', 'a+')
 x = True
 while x == True:
     print("Enter new location to enter")
     new_entry = str(input('Start with \'web\' if it\'s a web page\n'))
     fw.write(new_entry)

     y = input('New Data? Y/N\n')

     if y == 'N' or y == 'n':
         fw.close()
         break
 fw.close()
Setup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what `Start()` does, it must be ignored in answers, so far...

I wouldn't bother to close the file myself, but let a `with` statement do the job properly.

Following script works at least:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def Setup():
    with open('AutoLoader.txt', 'a') as fw:
        while True:
            print("Enter new location to enter")
            new_entry = str(input("Start with 'web' if it's a web page\n"))
            fw.write(new_entry + "\n")
            y = input('New Data? Y/N\n')
            if y in ['N', 'n']:
                break

        #Start()


Setup()
```

See:

```
nico@ometeotl:~/temp$ ./test_script3.py                                                                                                                
Enter new location to enter
Start with 'web' if it's a web page
First user's entry
New Data? Y/N
N
nico@ometeotl:~/temp$ ./test_script3.py
Enter new location to enter
Start with 'web' if it's a web page
Another user's entry
New Data? Y/N
N
nico@ometeotl:~/temp$ cat AutoLoader.txt 
First user's entry
Another user's entry
nico@ometeotl:~/temp$
```

Also note that a possibly missing AutoLoader.txt at start would be created automatically.